# Append div upto 5 times and ignore more than 5 - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating dynamic div, which is in for loop.

```
length = //some number from 1 to 10;
for(i=1; i<length; i++) 
{
     if(i > 5)
     {
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         ...
         // Ignore further appending div's greater than 5 and show ...
     }
     else // number less than 5
     {
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
     }
}
```

Basically if my `length` is more than 5, Append div upto 5 times, and how to ignore further appending showing ...

Comment: simply you can do it with if(i<=5) { append div here.} not use else part this may help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want the div to be append a maximum of 5 times, given any length you could do the following:

```
length = //some number from 1 to 10;
for(i=1; i<length; i++) 
{
   if(i > 5)
   {
     break;
   }
   <div></div>
}
```

U can check if the current number is greater than 5, if so break the loop and continue with any code that is beyong the loop.